# PWA ServiceWorkerRegistration.pushManger.getSubscription().then(...) not executing

Tags: javascript, promise, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

In the following code:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((swreg) => {
alert('serviceWorker ready');
        swreg.pushManager.getSubscription().then((sub) => {
alert('got subscription');
        ...
```

serviceWorker.ready execeutes (as indicated by the subsequent alert), but the promise callback after pushManager.getSubscription() is never invoked, and there are no errors in the console. Any suggestions as to what's going wrong here?

Comment: have you considered a `.catch` to see if the promise rejects?